# Will there be any recoverable data on the internal harddrive when i run a java Application on a USB-Stick?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, usb-drive

Lets assume I have a Java Application which stores data in a sqlite database. The application itself and its database are saved on a USB-Stick or any other external hardrive etc.  So the question is: If I plug the USB-Stick in a computer and run the program, work with it store some data in the sqlite database, will there be any recoverable temporary data stored on the internal hard drive?

Comment: Sounds like a system admin question, more than a programming one. You may need to ask this question in another community, and give more precision about the host operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running this on Windows or Linux, by default, no. Generally speaking when you read/write data from a removable device the only temporary data you'll have on the target PC is the disk cache (RAM) that buffers the reads/writes to the device. This memory is by design never cached to disk, even when the system is swapping (cache doesnt swap, only process memory swaps).

Data from your application may be in on disk in the form of swap-file contents while the application is running, because at some point your program will run and it'll use load that data from disk into the process memory space - but this would be the case regardless of whatever storage medium you use.

Word of warning though: even if you're prepared to live with this swap-only scenario, the USB stick is a generally poor database medium. OS's tend to keep the caches for these things reasonably small, because at any second you could yank the USB stick out and the files could become corrupted. It's astronomically poor form to run databases from USB devices for this reason, as the order of writes to the device may violate the write-ahead logging protocol or otherwise destroy consistency.

You could also never be sure that something else like an AV Scanner or other application isn't copying the data off the removable device for some reason, such as processing files. Assume the worst and you'll be rarely disappointed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! You helped me a lot.